# Admin checkbox in sign up form does not reflect true in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancancan

I've added an admin checkbox to the devise sign up form to denote whether a given user signs up as admin or not, however when user is created in DB, admin still commits as false.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @validatable) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    <%= check_box_tag(:admin, "admin") %>

  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div>
</div>
```

DB Schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  end
```

Comment: How are you passing the admin value to the params? Can you post the controller code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). In your **ApplicationController** add this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :admin
  end
end
```

Read more about that on [Devise's repository](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).